# How to Check Two condition in populate in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am able to check one condition when performing populate with this query

`populate(path : 'nextschema' , match : {'company.brand' : 'ABC'})`

but want to check two condition when populating.

```
 'company.brand' : 'ABC' && 'company.brand.length == 1'
```

i am stuck here , please someone help me.

Comment: I think you need to show us what you've done so far with the second condition. Show us the error, etc

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly.

```
 $match : {$and : [{'potent_substance.name' : {$size : 1}},
                     {'potent_substance.name' : molecule}]}
```